# How do you filter a certain number and find the range on Microsoft Access when using min/max on Query (filter button does not work in this case)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

For class, I was required to find the range of the convicts but some of the ages are `-1` because it is unknown.

How do I filter the `-1` and use the lowest positive number?

Here are some pictures explaining what doesn’t work and what the result is when I try it.

> This is my database:

[image]

> This is how it looks:

[image]

What doesn't work?

- Filtering `-1` in the property sheet
- Filtering `-1` afterwards on the query
- Adding `>0` into the criteria
- Adding `>0 and <100` into the criteria

I spent three lessons trying to solve this, please help!

EDIT:

[image: The edited one]

Comment: Add a screenshot of your data in table then show your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine for me:

```sql
SELECT
    Min([Age leaving england]) AS MinAge,
    Max([Age leaving england]) AS MaxAge
FROM
    Convicts
WHERE
    [Age leaving england] <> -1
```

To use it, switch the view of your query to `sql` and paste the query.

**Edit:**

This is how the query looks in design view:

[image]

Comment: Do I put <> -1 into the criteria?

Comment: So you want to modify your existing query in Design View? I added my query as Design View to my answer to show you how it looks like.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot try it right now because all the work is saved onto my school computers but I appreciate your answer a lot. Thank you so so much!

Comment: My pleasure. Just give me feedback when you tested it.

Comment: Almost. Instead of showing just the minimum and the maximum, it is showing all of it. Like this: (I added the picture into the question because I couldn't add it here. Also, when I add ascending/descending in the "Sort:" , it changes the order of all the ages.

Comment: That was badly phrased. Instead of just showing just the oldest age and just the youngest age, it shows all of the ages. Also, both columns have the ages ascending instead of one of starting from the lowest and the second starting from the highest.

Comment: Did you exactly use my query for the test, or did you modify it? The result you showed in your edit doesn't fit to my query.